# Как найти ограничивающую сферу (boundingSphere) у Object3D?

Tags: javascript, three.js

Загружаю object3D обьект,у него есть свойство children. Это массив []

я так понимаю, мне нужно добраться до children [Mesh] (см. скриншот 2)

Там лежит массив и  у него есть свойство bounting Sphere  (cм. скриншот 1)[image: введите сюда описание изображения].

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но когда пытаюсь добраться таким образом object.children[0].children, undefined

Как мне получить ее?

Получил объект со свойством boundingSphere: Sphere {center: Vector3, radius: 1.345125298235171} таким образом:

container.children[0].children[0].geometry

как мне теперь получить свойство boundingSphere? если просто обращаюсь к нему, то получаю undefined

Comment: `object.children[0].geometry.boundingSphere`

Comment: получаю undefined.
Может быть потому что я его помещаю в контейнер

   const container = new THREE.Object3D();

 container.add(object);

Comment: Если простов ывести object.children
 то получаю object []

Comment: []
0
:
Group {uuid: "FDF17F2A-563D-42F3-8B3C-878C76405554", name: "", type: "Group", parent: Object3D, children: Array(1), …}
length
:
1

Comment: если не помещаю в контейнер Object3D, то тогда sphere = null

Comment: добрался до объекта, в котором свойство 
boundingSphere: Sphere {center: Vector3, radius: 1.345125298235171}

Comment: но когда делаю просто
.....geometry.boundingSphere  то получаю undefined

Comment: Получила объект со свойством boundingSphere: Sphere {center: Vector3, radius: 1.345125298235171}
container.children[0].children[0].geometry

как мне теперь получить свойство boundingSphere? 

если просто вызываю, то получаю undefined

Comment: ДОПИСАЛ В СООБЩЕНИЕ ВВЕРХУ

Comment: `container.children[0].children[0].geometry.boundingSphere` не работает?

Comment: можно сначала выполнить `.computeBoundingSphere()` и уже потом пытаться получить доступ к сфере.

Comment: Да, помогло. спасибо!

Comment: Пожалуйста. Было бы за что :)